# jQuery AJAX post not working, but works with curl

Tags: jquery, ajax, post, curl, basecamp

I'm trying to make a post request via ajax using jQuery (for the BaseCamp API), and I can't seem to get it to work.  I can get it to work using curl just fine, so I know it's something I'm doing wrong with jQuery.  Here's the curl command which works:

```
curl -H "Accept: application/xml" -H "Content-Type: application/xml" -u my.user.name:my.password -d "<time-entry><person-id>123456</person-id><date>08/23/2009</date><hours>8</hours><description>This is a test.</description></time-entry>" https://my.url.updatelog.com/todo_items/1234567/time_entries.xml
```

and here's the code I'm trying with jQuery:

```
var post_url = bc_base_url + "/todo_items/" + todo_id + "/time_entries.xml";
var xmlData = "<time-entry><person-id>" + bc_user_id + "</person-id>" + 
        "<date>" + date + "</date>" +
        "<hours>" + time + "</hours>" +
        "<description>" + description + "</description>" + 
        "</time-entry>";
$.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: post_url,
                data: xmlData,
                dataType: "xml",
                contentType: "application/xml",
                username: "my.user.name",
                password: "my.password",
                processData: false,
                success: function(msg) {
                  alert("successfully posted! msg: " + msg + ", responseText = " + this.responseText);
                },
                error: function (xmlHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                  alert("error : " + textStatus + ", errorThrown = " + errorThrown);
                  alert("this.reponseText = " + this.responseText);
                }
            })
```

Anyone have any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: what comes back as the error when you view it in Firebug?  Could it be cross-domain issues?

Comment: Are you posting to the same domain?

Comment: Just FYI, the link in the accepted answer goes to a Go-Daddy parked domain page.

Comment: It's OK, @JoshuaMiller, I replaced it with a link to archive.org's copy of the page.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As karim79 said, you can't post to a different domain.

See [Nathan's post](http://web.archive.org/web/20101022211741/http://www.nathanm.com/ajax-bypassing-xmlhttprequest-cross-domain-restriction/) for more options.

Answer (score 2):

Post it to your server, pass the post onto basecamp from the application code, and pass the messages back down.